# escape code \" prints both \". Anyway to put a " in to a string.?

Tags: string, haskell

```
let ans = stringConcat ["<a href=","\"",str,"\"",">",strr,"</a>"]
                putStr ("\nOutput :" ++show (ans))
```

when I print this answer is `Output :"<a href=\"www.test.com\">testing</a>"` 
I want to know why the extra `\` is printing. `\"` suppose to be the escape code for double quotes. yet again it prints both `\"`. I want to know why this happening and is there any way to put a `"` is side a string..?

concat function

```
stringConcat::[String]->String 
stringConcat xs= concat xs
```

Comment: You don't need special `stringConcat` version for string. `concat` could be used directly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, `\"` is the correct escape code for double quotes, so the string `ans` contains the double quotes as you expected.

The problem is that you're then using `show`, which is a function for showing values like they would appear in Haskell code, which means that strings with double quotes in them have to be escaped.

```
> putStrLn (show "I said \"hello\".")
"I said \"hello\"."
```

So if you don't want that, just don't use `show`:

```
> putStrLn "I said \"hello\"."
I said "hello".
```

Comment: What's weird is that the escaping works for a single quote when using show \' just not for \".

Comment: Sorry I didn't actually write samples.  What I'm seeing is that the escaping works as expected for a single quote but not for a double quote.  Typing `"\""` at the ghci prompt yields `"\""`, but `"\'"` yields `"'"`

Comment: @bshields: That's because there is no need to escape a single quote in a string, so it doesn't. Whether you escaped it anyway when you entered it doesn't make any difference. That was taken care of when your expression was parsed, long before `show` was even run. All it sees is a list of characters, which it will format according to its own rules

Answer (score 7):

Don't `show` a String.

```
let ans = stringConcat ["<a href=","\"",str,"\"",">",strr,"</a>"]
putStr ("\nOutput :" ++ ans)
```

Also, what is `stringConcat`?

Comment: Got it... stringConcat is concat function

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try this

```
let ans = stringConcat ["<a href=","'",str,"'",">",strr,"</a>"]
```

Comment: I need double quotes not single